# what is the usage of web3.db.putString() ? does it log the event on node level?

Tags: web3js

what is the usage of `web3.db.putString()`? does it log the event on node level?  I am trying to store some information using this method I am getting below exception.

code snippet:

```
web3.db.putString('testDB', 'prod1', myContractReturned.address);
var value = web3.db.getString('testDB', 'prod1');
```

Output: "The method db_putString does not exist/is not available"

Comment: From the Api documentation "This method should be called, when we want to store a string in the local leveldb database.", so maybe you don't have well defined the DB, is it possible?